# How to send ajax request one by one on same page in particular block of code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone I am a bit confused to send a request using ajax. I can send a request using first text-field (using onkeyup event) and also getting response properly as I needed.

But now I want to send a request from second text-field also (using onkeyup event) on the same URL and this time the ajax call should execute another block of code. But I am unable to do it. Please help me to get the proper result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="qualityname">Quality Name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualityname" placeholder="Enter quality name" name="qualityname" list="addlist">
    <datalist id="addlist" class="response"></datalist>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="qualitycolor">Product Color(number on shadecard):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualitycolor" placeholder="Enter product color" name="qualitycolor" list="addlist1">
    <datalist id="addlist1" class="response1"></datalist>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
/*Code for first text-field ajax request*/
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#qualityname').keyup(function(){
          if(!($('#qualityname').val() == '')){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'scripts.php',
              data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data){
              $('.response').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function(){
              alert('data not post');
            });
            return false;
          }
          else{
            $('#response').html('<span></span>');
          }
        });

/*Code for second text-field ajax request*/
        $('#qualitycolor').keyup(function(){
          if(!($('#qualitycolor').val() == '')){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'scripts.php',
              data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data){
              $('.response1').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function(){
              alert('data not post');
            });
            return false;
          }
          else{
            $('#response1').html('<span></span>');
          }
        });
      });
```

**script.php**

```
 include "connection.php";

/*code for response first text-field request*/
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $qualityname = $_POST['qualityname'];
    $sql = "select DISTINCT quality_name from products where quality_name like '".$qualityname."%' limit 10";
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option>".$row['quality_name']."</option>";
    }

    /*code for response second text-field request*/     
}
```

Comment: _But I am unable to do it_... You have to be a little more precise than that. What exactly does not work as expected, do you get any error(s)?

Comment: you do not have any `$_POST['qualityname'];` for the second one since the name is `qualitycolor` or did not post all your code

Comment: @lovelace yes i added code into php for handling second request but it was not running. I am unable to decide how i can differ the request in php file whether it is coming from which ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that each field will be available in the POST array separately depending upon which text field is being edited so you can fork the logic in PHP based upon the existence, in the POST array, of a particular field. In this case `isset` seems appropriate - or `empty` ~ so you can test `if( isset( $_POST['qualityname'] ) )` etc

As the code was potentially vulnerable to sql injection I rewrote the queries to use `prepared statements` to give an idea how you should handle user input ~ it's not been debugged so there might be the odd mistook in there.

```
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ){

    include "connection.php";

    # test if the field is in post array... 
    if( isset( $_POST['qualityname'] ) ){
        $sql='select distinct quality_name from products where quality_name like ? limit 10';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){
            $qualityname = '%'.$_POST['qualityname'].'%';
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$qualityname );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            if( $res ){
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $name );

                while( $stmt->fetch() ) printf( '<option value="%s">%s', $name, $name );
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }


    if( isset( $_POST['qualitycolor'] ) ){

        /* assumed same table and similar variables... edit as appropriate */
        $sql='select distinct colour_name from products where colour_name like ? limit 10';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){
            $qualitycolor='%'.$_POST['qualitycolor'].'%';
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$qualitycolor );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            if( $res ){
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $colour);

                while( $stmt->fetch() ) printf( '<option value="%s">%s', $colour, $colour);
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```